# embeds_many multiple times with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

i just started working with mongoid and have a question about model relation

```
class DefineGroup
 embedded_in :system_mag, :class_name => "SystemMag"
end

class SystemMag
 embeds_many :user_groups, :class_name => "DefineGroup"
 embeds_many :system_groups, :class_name => "DefineGroup"
end
```

I can see only user_groups in database return. Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: I face the exactly same question, Do you figure it out already?

Comment: @stanliu sadly but no, i had to find another way to do this

Comment: Could you please provide your another way? Maybe it will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @stanliu well, they have same structure so i only embed 1 of them(user_groups), clone it and use it as system_group